# example code to load sqlite data into a handsontable

Tags: html, flask, handsontable

example code to load sqlite data into a handsontable. im new to this assume table of student id and student names ( im using python and flask) and I would like to display this data in a handsontable.
I have thought about  using render_template() but do not understand how to get the data in to the javascript

i would just like to see a handsontable with student id and name in it, nothing fancy. when creating the container i do not know how to get the data from my sqlite query into javascript? Im not using angular or vue frameworks

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@13.1/dist/handsontable.full.min.js">          </script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@13.1/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" />


<div id="example" class="hot"> test</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
const container = document.querySelector('#example');
const hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: [
    ['', 'Tesla', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Ford'],
    ['2019', 11, 11, 12, 13],
    ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ],
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  height: 'auto',
  licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation' // for non-commercial use only
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.